# Should I include a research in my thesis which does not have a direct connection to its title?

Tags: phd, thesis, all-but-dissertation

Let's say that my Ph.D. project was about mitigating the problem **X** (e.g. analyzing the specific type of datasets) from different perspectives (CS field), for which one of the methods I have developed was algorithm **A**.

However, I also developed the algorithm **B**, which belongs to the same overarching category that also Algorithm **A** belongs to, but it does not apply to problem **X**.

Even though I also published Algorithm B as an individual conference paper, I'm not sure if I can bring it in my dissertation. It is a novel method, but not related to the main problem (or the dataset type) that my Ph.D. project is about. So, I'm not sure if I can include it in my Ph.D. thesis despite the time I spent developing it.

Comment: This is something you should primarily discuss with your advisor.

Comment: I don't see how we can meaningfully answer this without knowing your field, paper and the algorithms in question.

Answer (score 2):

In many cases, it comes down to your defense and the work you've done, and the thesis is a document for you. You can include, or not include whatever work you want.

I'm speaking from a PhD in the natural sciences in the US, different countries and subjects have different rules and guidelines.

Comment: I think its more "you can include what your advisor wants".